# Advice on whether a mixed-effects model is suitable

Tags: mixed-model

I would be very grateful for the opinion of someone, with more experience of mixed-effects models than myself, on whether the following sounds reasonable:

I would like to look at whether several variables, such as blood test results, significantly change among diabetic cats as they enter diabetic remission. I have the variable results from a selection of diabetic cats who successfully entered remission, and also from a group of diabetic cats who never achieved remission. To analyse my data, I was planning to split the results from the remission cats into several groups according to their "stage" of remission. These groups are:

1) more than 45 days before stopping remission
2) less than 30 days before stopping insulin
3) less than 28 days after stopping insulin
4) more than 28 days after stopping insulin (in long-standing remission)
There is also a group 5 made up of the cats who never entered remission.

I was then planning on using a mixed effects model to study the effect of Group (my fixed effect) on my various outcome variables. I was going to add each cat's identity as a random effect. All the cats in group 5 are unique, but cats who entered remission might contribute samples to any of groups 1 to 4. Also, some cats might have several samples that are eligible for one, or several, of groups 1 to 4 e.g. a cat might have 2 samples that could technically be included in group 1. Unfortunately, not all remission cats have a sample in every one of groups 1 to 4.

I would be very grateful if anyone could advise me on whether the above seems suitable, and whether it would be possible to include multiple samples from an individual cat in any of groups 1 to 4? I would also be grateful to know which covariance structure might be most suitable.

Thank you very much in advance!